# Memorylessness of geometric distribution- computating mistake

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I would like to show that

$X-n|X\ge n\sim G(p)$, where $X$ has a geometric distribution $G(p)$.

Hence

$P(X-n=k|X\ge n)=\frac{P(X=n+k)}{P(X\ge n)}=\frac{p(1-p)^{n+k-1}}{\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}p(1-p)^{k-1}}=\frac{p(1-p)^{n+k-1}}{(1-p)^{n-1}}=p(1-p)^k$.

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is there are two definitions of a geometric distribution. You've calculated as if the infimum of $X$'s support is $1$, but it needs to be $0$. (The case $k=0$ is an easy sanity check to verify this; clearly $P(X=n|X\ge n)\ne0$.) Your calculation *strategy* is fine but, because we start at $0$, the $-1$s in exponents shouldn't be there. Then $p(1-p)^k$ is, in fact, the value of $P(G(p)=k)$.

Comment: Okaaay, I didn't know that we can consider Geometric distribution starting from zero... I saw solutions of the form: show that $P(X>n+m|X\ge n)\sim G(p)$, but I understand that there is also a zero-starting Geometric distribution?

Comment: @mrwooo It's just the distribution you're familiar with, with $1$ subtracted from it. If you toss a (possibly biased) coin until you get heads, the number of tosses is geometrically distributed starting at $1$, but the number of tails is geometrically distributed starting at $0$.

Comment: Okay, so we have two definitions of Geometric distribution depending on what we are counting right?

Comment: @mwrooo Yes. What this calculation shows is that it needs to start at $0$ to be memoryless.